# why dsound CommitDeferredSettings call regopenkeyex?

Tags: performance, audio

i use vtune to analyse my application, but i found a unexpected hotspot.

IDirectSound3DListener8::CommitDeferredSettings, i don't know why this function will call RegOpenKeyEx.

my os is win7 64.
i just use one listener, and i just call CommitDeferredSettings once every frame.

any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks.

vtune screenshot is in [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/643087-why-dsound-commitdeferredsettings-call-regopenkeyex/)

Comment: Maybe it calls it once to read a global setting it did not read before. Do you see if every `CommitDeferredSettings` call you do involves touching registry?

Comment: it should be, if it just call once, it would not use 3.x second.